# Instagram icon not inline with text in table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am building an email signature so hence using tables. I have tried things such as display inline-block and position relative on the image for the Instagram icon but nothing seems to work.

```
style="width:20px;height:20px;object-fit:cover;
```

here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/alexmciver/pen/zYPJxPW

Comment: just try vertical-align property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use vertical-align for align this item

```
<img src="https://logowik.com/content/uploads/images/instagram-glyph.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px;object-fit:cover;vertical-align: middle;">
```

Comment: Jus add vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 0):

Use this style settings on the span containing Instagram icon, like this

```
<span style="display: flex; align-items: center;">

</span>
```

Here is your html snippet with instagram icon inline with text

```
    <span style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;line-height:32px;font-weight:400;color:#ab9e7f;display:inline; padding:0px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
       <img src="https://logowik.com/content/uploads/images/instagram-glyph.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px;object-fit:cover; margin-right: .25rem" />
        doubledutchdrinks
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, a way is using from `sub` or `sup` tags. Here wrap your icon inside a `sub` tag:

```
<sub style="margin-right: 3px;">
  <img src="https://logowik.com/content/uploads/images/instagram-glyph.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px;object-fit:cover;">
</sub>
```